# Problem in maintaining versions of repository on GitHub

Tags: github

I have a github repository which contains some python files and some folders.

Now, can I create an entirely new version of the entire repo, while simultaneously maintaining the previous version too.

I tried to create a new version of the repo by creating a new release. But in that I am unable to upload the folders as they are. It only allows us to upload binaries. So, how should I go about it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I wish to update the repo in such a way that the files outside the folders and inside the folders are updated while the folders remain the same, as do the file names"? Please read [ask].

Comment: I have done so. Please have a look

Comment: Creating a new version while simultaneously maintaining the previous version too is pretty much exactly what Git does. Have you done any Git tutorials? Are you comfortable with committing? Branching?

Comment: I am comfortable with commiting and branching. But I only use the website to do that and not git for Windows.

Comment: You're probably going to have to learn to do that locally. So what's the problem here? Why can't you just checkout an old revision to see what the code looked like, e.g. at a particular tag? Is it that you want two separate copies of your code, in different directories, not just one? Or that you want to have two parallel active lines of development, e.g. a maintenance branch based on 1.0 where you do bugfixes and a new branch for 2.0?

Comment: Yes, I need to maintain two versions of the repo. ver 1 and ver 2 (which is version 1 + some new files).

Comment: Okay, and if you already know about branching why can't you just have a "ver 1 branch" and a "ver 2 branch"?

Comment: The problem is that branches are meant to be committed to the main branch. But I don't want them to merge ever. They should run parallel.

Comment: "branches are meant to be committed to the main branch"—not necessarily. There are plenty of workflows for maintaining multiple long-running branches. Is that what you're asking? How to manage that?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. What options do I have?

Comment: That kind of question is off-topic here, but there are _tons_ of workflows out there, and you can modify them to suit your needs. (You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]). Search for "git workflows", review a few, and pick one. Most allow for multiple ongoing versions (it's very common to support old versions with bugfixes, for example, while continuing to work on the current version).